# Override default unhandled exception behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, g++, visual-studio-2015

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class TestException : public std::exception
{
public:
    char const* what() const throw() override { return msg_.c_str(); }

protected:
    std::string & message() throw() { return msg_; }

private:
    std::string msg_;
};

void ThrowIt()
{
    throw TestException();
}

int main()
{
    ThrowIt();
}
```

Running this when built in either Release or Debug on Windows compiled with Visual Studio results in program termination, same goes for when compiled with GCC on a Linux machine, the result is :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'TestException'
>   what(): Aborted

Both terminate the program once an unhandled exception is caught. Is this behaviour strictly system specific or is this specified by the standard? Is there a cross-platform way that I can reroute every exception not handled by `catch` to a handler instead of just terminating the program?

Comment: Why not just put a try/catch block in main to catch all unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**15.5.1** of the C++11 standard states:

> [...] when the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a thrown exception [...] `std::terminate()` is called. In the situation where no matching handler is found,
>   it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before `std::terminate()` is called.

So the termination is standard behavior, but whether or not you could recover from this situation is implementation-defined.  In any case there's no rerouting of the exception object.

You can also change the handler function (`typedef void (*terminate_handler)();`) called by `std::terminate()` with `terminate_handler set_terminate(terminate_handler f) noexcept;`and view it with `terminate_handler get_terminate() noexcept;`.

Comment: Editing the `std::terminate` handler doesn't allow me to view the exception that was thrown that caused the `std::terminate` in the first place, correct?

Comment: @JameyD Yup, that's all you get from the standard.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have an uncaught exception as there are no matching handle for your exception.  the behavior of this is covered in [except.terminate]

> In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less subtle error handling techniques. [ Note: These situations are:
>   [...]
>   - when the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a thrown exception (15.3), or
>   [...]

And then we have

> In such cases, std::terminate() is called (18.8.3). In the situation where no matching handler is found,
>   it is implementation-defined whether or not the stack is unwound before std::terminate() is called.

If you want to have "Top level" `catch` that will handle all exceptions in your program if the are not caught you could wrap the code in `main()` in a `try...catch` block.  Any exception not caught will move up per [except.handle]

> If no match is found among the handlers for a try block, the search for a matching handler continues in a
>   dynamically surrounding try block of the same thread.

You could also change the `std::terminate_handler` using [`std::set_terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate)

Comment: Yes, I know I have an uncaught exception, that was the goal of the program. I'm trying to avoid `catch(...)`. As stated in the question I'd like to know if you can add a cross-platform handler for exceptions that aren't caught by `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what standard guarantees but in practice with GCC, clang and MSVC you may use `std::current_exception()` inside terminate handler to handle the exception. Like this:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

void f()
{
    try
    {
        std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e)
    {
        
        std::clog << "exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set_terminate(f);
    throw std::runtime_error("oh no");
    return 0;
}
```